# In Flutter, when retrieving a DateTime parameter via API, how can I parse the time and convert it from "2019-10-30T20:30:00" to 8:30pm?

Tags: api, datetime, parsing, flutter

When retrieving class schedules via the API, the class times (in the API RESPONSE) are shown as "2019-10-30T20:30:00". I simply want to parse the Time and convert it to 12 hour time format?

Here is my code to extract the characters of the time at the moment...

---

```
Container(
    child: Text(data[index]['StartDateTime'][11].toString()),
  ),
   Container(
     child: Text(data[index]['StartDateTime'][12].toString()),
  ),
   Container(
     child: Text(data[index]['StartDateTime'][13].toString()),
  ),
   Container(
     child: Text(data[index]['StartDateTime'][14].toString()),
  ),
   Container(
     child: Text(data[index]['StartDateTime'][15].toString()),
```

---

The current output is like this:   20:30

Answer (score 1):

DateTime has a function called parse, it returns a DateTime object wich you can then manipulate with Flutter https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html

So you do

```
DateTime p = DateTime.parse('2019-10-30T20:30:00');
print('${p.hour}:${p.minute}');
```

and it prints 20:30

you can even calculate date differences , convert to String, etc.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

Just found this library: https://pub.dev/packages/intl. It seems to include the DateFormat library from the Dart API, which would do what you want as well.

### ORIGINAL

I don't think there is a built in way to get AM/PM time. You'll have to write some logic. Here's mine, could probably be made easier.

```
void main() {
  String time = '2019-10-30T20:30:00';
  DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(time);

  String formatted = formatDateWithAmPm(dateTime);

  print(formatted);
}

String formatDateWithAmPm(DateTime dateTime) {
  String amPm = 'am';
  if (dateTime.hour >= 12) {
    amPm = 'pm';
  }

  String hour = dateTime.hour.toString();
  if (dateTime.hour > 12) {
    hour = (dateTime.hour - 12).toString();
  }

  String minute = dateTime.minute.toString();
  if (dateTime.minute < 10) {
    minute = '0${dateTime.minute}';
  }

  return '$hour:$minute$amPm';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Derek, that's great. Ill try this out later to see how it works out!

Answer (score 0):

Try out this package, [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy)

```
var jiffy = Jiffy.parse("2019-10-30T20:30:00", pattern: "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss");

var time = jiffy.format("h:mm"); // 8:30
// or use default formats
var time = jiffy.jm; // 8:30 PM
```

You can also parse in your DateTime object

```
String time = '2019-10-30T20:30:00';
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(time);
Jiffy.parseFromDateTime(dateTime).format("h:mm"); // 8:30
```